# Verify (errorlevel) batch script commands and send mail with their output

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file

I have more batch files(cmd) as follows , that is executing some commands and print the output of their errorlevel code in a file and send an email to me with the output of the file :

```
@echo off

set RESEXE1=0
set RESEXE2=0

SET MyPath=D:\test\client
SET PATH=%MyPath%\;%PATH%
SET PATH=%MyPath%\schema;%PATH%
SET PATH=%MyPath%\xml;%PATH%
SET PATH=%MyPath%\xsl;%PATH%
SET PATH=%MyPath%\DashboardPlugins;%PATH%

:BEGIN

cd /d %MyPath%

set RESEXE1=%ERRORLEVEL%
echo RESEXE1 : %RESEXE1% > D:\Temp\logs\test.txt

START "test" /MIN test.exe -UEOD /ccu:file:test2.config /pcu:file:D:\scripts\test.config /p:Common/Log/Path=D:\Misys\logs\batch\test /p:Common/Log/Verbosity=Warning -S'Report Processing':":0 

set RESEXE2=%ERRORLEVEL%
echo RESEXE2 : %RESEXE2% >> D:\Temp\logs\test.txt

:ENDBATCH

if %RESEXE1% == 0 set RESEXE=0

if %RESEXE1% NEQ 0 set RESEXE=1

if %RESEXE2% == 0 set RESEXE=0

if %RESEXE2% NEQ 0 set RESEXE=1

echo RESEXE : %RESEXE% >> D:\Temp\logs\test.txt

echo %~n0%~x0 >> D:\Temp\logs\test.txt

IF %RESEXE% NEQ 0  Powershell.exe -executionpolicy remotesigned -File D:\Temp\aaa.ps1
```

The second part is my sendmail script :

```
$From = "them@test.com"
$To = "me@test.com"
#$Cc = "he@test.com"
$Subject = $scname
$Body = Get-Content -Path D:\Temp\logs\test.txt
#$Attachments = D:\Temp\test.txt
$SMTPServer = "test.com"
$SMTPPort = "25"
Send-MailMessage -From $From -to $To -Subject "[test][test] $Subject" -Body  ($body | Out-String) -SmtpServer $SMTPServer -port $SMTPPort –DeliveryNotificationOption OnSuccess
```

My question is , how can i declare a dynamic variable on batch(cmd) scripts, for every output file (ex: test.txt) that is generated with the errorcode and other info and use it in $body variable from sendmail script to output the content in email .

Comment: Surely this type of structure is better: `Set "MyPath=D:\test\client"`,   `Set "ToPath=%MyPath%;%MyPath%\schema;%MyPath%\xml;%MyPath%\xsl;%MyPath%\DashboardPlugins"`,   `Set "PATH=%ToPath%;%PATH%`.

Comment: PowerShell scripts can have parameters. See `help about_Parameters` for information about invoking a PowerShell script with parameters. See `help about_Functions` for information about writing a PowerShell script to use parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Batch file :

```
@echo off

set RESEXE1=0
set scname=%~n0%~x0
set scname2=%~n0.txt
set pathlog=D:\Temp\logs
set pathfilelog=%pathlog%\%scname2%

:BEGIN

cd h: > %pathfilelog% 2>&1

set RESEXE1=%ERRORLEVEL%
echo RESEXE1 : %RESEXE1% >> %pathfilelog%

:ENDBATCH

 if %RESEXE1% == 0 set RESEXE=0

 if %RESEXE1% NEQ 0 set RESEXE=1

echo RESEXE : %RESEXE% >> %pathfilelog%

 echo %~n0%~x0 >> %pathfilelog%

 IF %RESEXE% NEQ 0  Powershell.exe -executionpolicy remotesigned -File D:\Temp\aaa.ps1 "%scname%" "%scname2%" "%pathfilelog%"
```

mail script file :

```
$scname=$args[0] 
$scname2=$args[1]
$pathfilelog=$args[2]  

$From = "test@test.com"
$To = "test@test.com"
#$Cc = "test@test.com"
$Subject = $scname
$Body = Get-Content -Path $pathfilelog
#$Attachments = D:\Temp\test.txt
$SMTPServer = "test.test.com"
$SMTPPort = "25"
Send-MailMessage -From $From -to $To -Subject "[test][test] $Subject - Failed" -Body  ($body | Out-String) -SmtpServer $SMTPServer -port $SMTPPort –DeliveryNotificationOption OnSuccess
```

That solved my problem , ty guys .